# Python circular reference : How do I go about this specific case?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I'm working with tornado and websockets(sockjs) and having trouble while handling incoming messages, getting around this specific case which is that of a circular class reference. The issue is not related to websockets per se, but essentially the cyclicity.

Here's the file which defines the class `Socket` for handing incoming messages, it also defines the class `Async` which needs the class `Socket`. `on_message` is triggered when a message is received from the client :

```
from logicmodule import Logic

class Async(object):

    def notify_user(self, *args):
        print("Notifying user!")
        Socket.send_message("ASYNC CALLBACK: notify_user ARGS: {:}\n".format(args))

async = Async()
logic = Logic(async)

class Socket(SockJSConnection):

    clients = set()

    def on_open(self, request):

        print("Opened Connection...")
        self.clients.add(self)

    def send_message(self, message, operation):

        return self.send(json.dumps({
            'operation': operation,
            'data': message,
        }))

    def on_message(self, msg):
        data = json.loads(msg)
        projectData = logic.create_project(data['project_info'])
        self.send_message(projectData, data['operation'])
```

EDIT:
The Logic Class implements one method `create_project`, takes the `async` class as a parameter whose method `notify_user` is called within the `create_project` method. `notify_user` requires an instance of `Socket` class which can be created only on an incoming message in the `on_open` method. That instance will be a persistent connection over which the message will be sent back to user in the `notify_user` method.

This is may be a easy hack, but I'm new to python. How do I provide an instance of Socket to `Async` on an incoming message which has to be given to `logic` beforehand ? Please help, thanks!

Comment: You are already providing it in your solution, What's the problem?

Comment: @hspandher he has circular dependency; file A imports B and file B imports A

Comment: What are the two modules A and B here? I mean you haven't describerdwhere are you getting circular dependency issue.

Comment: Does `Async` need the *class* `Socket` or an *instance of `Socket`*? In the example `Socket.send_message()` doesn't seem to make sense, since `send_message()` is not a static/class method.

Comment: @dhke It needs the instance, but the instance can be created only on an incoming message. I'm not sure how do I instantiate Socket within on_mesage and then give it to logic.

Comment: @mystikacid I might be misunderstanding this, but `on_message()` has  a `Socket` instance in `self`. Is there a problem with just passing `self`?

Comment: @dhke The problem is I cannot pass the self to a particular method in Logic. I would need the async instance available throughout the class scope.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule to avoid circular dependency, if file `A` needs `C` from file `B` and file `B` needs `D` from file `A`, maybe `C` and `D` belongs together in some other file.

Although, if `A` needs `B` and `B` needs `A` is the case, maybe both `A` and `B` belongs together in same module.